# Nodejs + Typescript: How to define response structure with model

Tags: node.js, typescript, decorator

I am new to `nodejs` and `express`.

I am trying to create a rest service using [`ts-express-decorators`](https://github.com/Romakita/ts-express-decorators).

In my `controller` I have a `POST` method which updates a user data and returns the updated result.

But the collection which I am trying to update has few fields which I do not want to send to the user.

My `controller.ts`

```
import { Controller, Get, PathParams, Authenticated, Required, Req, Post, Res, BodyParams } from 'ts-express-decorators';
import { Returns } from 'ts-express-decorators/lib/swagger';

@Controller('/users')
@Authenticated()
export class UserController {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {    }

@Post('/update')
@Returns(UserResponse)
async updateUser(
    @Req() req,
    @Res() res) {
    const data = await this.userService.updateUser(req.body)
    return data;
    }
}
```

this is `user.ts`

```
export class UserResponse {
    @JsonProperty()
    email: string;

    @JsonProperty()
    firstName: string;

    @JsonProperty()
    lastName: string;

    @JsonProperty()
    picture?: string;

    @JsonProperty()
    _id: string;

}
```

I want to structure my response as in `UserResponse` class. But currently it returns the json from the collection will all the data.

`service.ts`

```
async updateUser(data) {
    return await this.userRepository.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: data.id}, data);
}
```

The default method in the boilerplate follows the same structure.

Pls point out what I am missing or is there a better option to achieve this.

I am able to restructure the response json in the `controller.ts` but I do not wish to do that.

My current Response:

```
{
"_id": "5b6aee50f31f19156c014933",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"password": "ZAUzmguxklW7769Uc0CrUi",
"firstName": "Test",
"lastName": "Test",
"__v": 0,
"picture": "",
"tokens": []
}
```

Expected Response:

```
{
"_id": "5b6aee50f31f19156c014933",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"firstName": "Test",
"lastName": "Test",
"picture": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now when your code is transpiled to JavaScript it will simple return the result of `await this.userService.updateUser(req.body)`.

You will need to create a new instance of `UserResponse` from the `data`variable.  Explicitly setting all the fields you want to set in your instance of `UserResponse`. Then you have to return that instance of `UserResponse` instead of `data` variable.

Example:

```
const response = new UserResponse();
response._id = data._id;
response.email = data.email;
response.firstName = data.firstName;
response.lastName = data.lastName;
return response;
```

I would probably create a new constructor for `UserResponse` that takes the required arguments.

Comment: Could you pls provide a simple example on how to achieve that? Should i do like `new UserResonse()` and so on?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do that. Added an example.